Serdica Journal Template
I'm looking for a LaTeX template for an article in Serdica Mathematical Journal.
The journal does not offer such a template, nor a serdica.cls or serdica.sty file.

In almost all cases if a journal does not supply a class file you should use basic latex markup and article class or similar.
The author requirements for that journal are here
http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/instr_2023.html
I do not know the details here but often the final copy is set not using TeX or using private macros specific to the publisher so using non standard macros designed to approximate the journal design does not help the publisher at all, it just complicates the conversion process to the required form as it is starting with a non-standard set of macros and document commands.
